# cakephp 2.9.7 $this->auth->login() always returns bool(false) for vallid users also

Tags: cakephp

I have checked all the sinarios mentioned in the stackoverflow related to my problem.Nothing is working fine for me.Please help me in solving this problem.

table to hold users data

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(50),
    password VARCHAR(255),
    role VARCHAR(20),
    created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
);
```

app/Controller/UsersController.php file looks like this

```
<?php
// app/Controller/UsersController.php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {

  public function beforeFilter() {
  parent::beforeFilter();
  // Allow users to register and logout.
  $this->Auth->allow('add', 'logout');
}

public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
     pr($this->request->data);
    // echo $this->Flash->render('auth');
    //  die();
    var_dump($this->Auth->login());
    //  die();
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}

public function logout() {
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
    public function index() {
        $this->User->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
    }

    public function view($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        $this->set('user', $this->User->findById($id));
    }

    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Flash->error(
                __('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')
            );
        }
    }

    public function edit($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Flash->error(
                __('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')
            );
        } else {
            $this->request->data = $this->User->findById($id);
            unset($this->request->data['User']['password']);
        }
    }

    public function delete($id = null) {
        // Prior to 2.5 use
        // $this->request->onlyAllow('post');

        $this->request->allowMethod('post');

        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->User->delete()) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('User deleted'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('User was not deleted'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
?>
```

app/model/User.php file looks like this

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class User extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                'message' => 'A username is required'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                'message' => 'A password is required'
            )
        ),
        'role' => array(
            'valid' => array(
                'rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'author')),
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid role',
                'allowEmpty' => false
            )
        )
    );
    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
        //echo $passwordHasher->hash($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        //echo $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] ;
        //exit();

        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
        );
   }
   //echo "true";
    return true;

}
}
?>
```

app/View/Users/login.ctp

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Flash->render('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?>
        </legend>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
</div>
```

app/controller/AppController.php file looks like this

```
<?php
@copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.Controller
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

/**
 * Application Controller
 *
 * Add your application-wide methods in the class below, your controllers
 * will inherit them.
 *
 * @package     app.Controller
 * @link        http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller
 */

class AppController extends Controller {
  public function index() {

    }
  //public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar');

    public function View() {

    }

  public $components = array('Session',
        'Flash',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'posts',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'pages',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                )

            ),
            'authorize' => array('Controller')
        )
    );



    public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // Admin can access every action
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
}

}
```

I have created all the files exactly as same as that in the https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html tutorial.But when i go to Users/login Url It always returns Invalid Username,or password for valid Username or password also.

Comment: Can you provide the Auth configuration as well

Comment: I have added AppController.php also

Comment: Please put your database structure as well. Your code may lead to truncate part of the hashed password and cause this problem.

Comment: I have added Users table structure also.Any suggestions please.